# Laravel 5 Eloquent high memory usage while updating model

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I've stumbled upon a very strange issue regarding unjustifiably high memory usage when calling `update()` method on a Eloquent query result.

This is the piece of code where it happens:

```
if ($found_something = Something::where("column_a", "value_a")->first()) {
    if ($found_something_else = SomethingElse::where("column_b", "value_b")->first() {
        if ($result = Result::where("something_else_id", $found_something_else->id)->first()) {
               $result->update([
                   "something_else_id" => null,
                   "something_id" => $found_something->id
               ]);
        }

        $found_something_else->delete();
    }

    // Some other code...

}
```

Before calling the `update()` on `$result` everything works fine and memory usage stays at ~17MB. If I let the code continue running the `update()` method or even if I use the `save()` method instead it starts to consume memory like crazy until it finally crashes with this error:

> `PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory`

I've set `memory_limit 2048M` but it is apparently still not enough.

Also I've tried to call the `update()` method without giving the array of fields that need to be updated and it seems to run fine.

What could cause such behavior and what can be done about this?

Thanks

Comment: Do your models have a lot of relationships and/or use `protected $with` in them?

Comment: @btl `Something` model has 7 relations and `SomethingElse` has 8 relations, `Result` has 3 relations. What is strange is that this is the first time I encounter this issue without even including any of those relations in these queries. I have some complex queries involving several relations and they work perfectly fine.

Comment: something_else_id is fine to be null ?

Comment: I suspect you may have a circular dependency graph occurring. I've encountered this and it's my first suspicion when database memory usage spins out of control. Have you added or modified any relation recently?

Comment: @Svetoslav I don't care too much about `something_else_id` since in case it is null the query would just not retrieve anything.

Comment: @btl No, I didn't modify any model for quite a while. Everything else is still working excepting this particular case. How can I check if it is indeed a circular dependency graph you're talking about happening?